# Rails Plugin|Gem that emails error reports?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, error-reporting

can you recommend me a Rails Plugin/Gem that emails error reports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Exception Notifier](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/exception_notifier) plugin emails current request, session, and environment, and also gives a backtrace of the exception.

Comment: You might want to consider http://www.hoptoadapp.com/pages/home or http://www.getexceptional.com/ instead.